# На кассе или за кассой

Tags: грамотная-речь

Женщина на кассе/за кассой улыбнулась. Как лучше?

Comment: В  вашем  случае  "за  кассой".

Comment: Кассирша улыбнулась.

Answer (score 3):

Женщина на кассе - разговорное выражение, имеющее значение"на этой услуге" . Есть выражение "на раздаче", "на заправке кроватей", "на уборке территории" , "я сегодня на воротах"- это из этой же серии.

Answer (score 1):

"За кассой", конечно: она же не на кассовом аппарате сидит. Впрочем, если улыбнувшаяся женщина не кассир, а предложно-падежная конструкция "на кассе" нормативна и означает "в очереди в кассу", выражение "женщина на кассе" можно использовать для указания на женщину, стоящую в очереди в кассу.

Comment: Может,"в очереди в кассу" всё-таки не "на кассе", а "на кассу"?

Answer (score 1):

Возможны оба выражения, но по стилю они разные.

Нейтральный стиль - "женщина за кассой". Фактически это "женщина, сидящая за кассой", сравнить: человек за рулем. Творительный падеж с предлогом ЗА обозначает ОБЛАСТЬ ДЕЙСТВИЯ глагола (в данном случае место нахождения работника). Такое выражение уместно в художественных текстах, а также в разговорной речи.

"Женщина на кассе" - это, скорее, деловой стиль, обозначение профессии, сравнить: секретарь на "ресепшн", на телефоне. Здесь мы имеем  разновидность местного (предложного) падежа, который определяет сферу трудовой и общественной деятельности: стоять на посту,на часах. Существительное с предлогом НА обозначает не физическое место нахождения сотрудника, а указывает его должность.